# Grouping data in elasticsearch taking whitespaces into account

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to execute aggregations the same way they're executed here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_executing_aggregations.html

The problem I'm facing at the moment is that some values in the fields have whitespaces. Imagine that a possible value is "El Paso". When I execute the following, I get buckets for "El" and for "Paso", but I don't get a bucket for "El Paso".

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/myIndex/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_city": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "city"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

My desired result is that each field is treated as an indivisible unit. How do I do this?

EDIT 1: Creating the index and importing the data again would take enormous amounts of time, since that index has millions of documents, so I would like a solution that doesn't involve doing all the work again.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make the index fields as **not_analysed** as mentioned in this [page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html) to achieve this

example

```
"title": {
    "type": "string",
    "fields": {
        "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
    }
}
```

Comment: "We can update a mapping to add a new field, but we can’t change an existing field from analyzed to not_analyzed." https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html If I try to, I get an "index_already_exists_exception".

Comment: try re-indexing the data, so that you can achieve this